# android -room - saving object in room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I've this json :

```
{
"products": [{
    "id": "150",
    "num": "7",
    "name": "450 SA"
}, {
    "id": "122",
    "num": "13",
    "name": "Gillette Blue"
}]}
```

I've created my models from it , i've these classes for it :

```
    @Entity
data class ProductsModel(
    @Json(name = "products")
    val products: List<Product>
)

@Entity
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: String,
    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @Json(name = "num")
    val num: String,
)
```

this is my DAO class for inserting data into my room database  :

```
@Dao
interface ProductsDAO {

// 2: Insert
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(product: ProductsModel)
```

When I want to run the application , I get this error :

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

How can I save these data into my database ?

Comment: You have to provide an implementation of ProductsDAO

Answer (score 3):

Room provides functionality for converting between primitive and boxed types but doesn't allow for object references between entities.

You can simply create a table that has 3 columns - id, name and num. So each row would be a different `Product`

**OR**

Your data base should only save the list of `Product`'s and you should provide a `TypeConverter`, which converts a `Product` class to and from a known type that Room can persist.

more about type converters  - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters)